# How do I write a single SQL statement for MySQL that checks a value and then does INSERT if true?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT pinpicsid
FROM user_collection
JOIN pin ON user_collection.pinid = pin.id
WHERE username = 'myuser'
AND pinpicsid = '98802';
```

If it returns blank (or no rows), I'd like to do an INSERT like this:

```
SELECT id INTO @id FROM pin WHERE pinpicsid = '98802';

INSERT INTO user_collection (pinid, username)
VALUES (@id, 'ethanwa');
```

Is there any possible way to combine all of these into one single statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just INSERT...SELECT?

```
INSERT INTO user_collection (pinid, username)
SELECT id, 'ethanwa' FROM pin WHERE pinpicsid = '98802';
```

Syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

If you need to enforce the uniqueness of pinid, but still want to update the username, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO user_collection (pinid, username)
SELECT id, 'ethanwa' FROM pin WHERE pinpicsid = '98802'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username = VALUES(username)
```

Without knowing more about your goals for this script, it's hard to get much more precise.

Comment: What if that value of `pinid` already exists in `user_collection`?  *Perhaps* the OP wants to define a uniqueness constraint over that column (in which case I'd agree with your answer), but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: @eggyal: fair point; I edited my answer to provide some guidance in that scenario.

Comment: Yes, I have now defined a uniqueness jointly for `username-pinid` columns on the `user_collection` table. So this answer should now work I assume?

Comment: Yes; just make sure you think about what you want to happen if that pinid/username combo already exists. You may just want `INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT ...` instead of `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`.